# Transforming NSMutableArray values

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I've been looking for this, but can't find the answer.

I have an NSMutableArray with values who_1, what_2, where_3 etc.

I want to transform this into who, what, where etc.

I already have the value of the integer as a variable, and _ is just a string.

What steps should I take to have all these arrayvalues transformed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSArray * arrB = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"apple_a",@"ball_b",@"cat_c",@"doll_d",nil]; 

 NSMutableArray * arrA = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for(NSString *strData in arrB)
    {
        NSArray *arr = [strData componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
        [arrA  addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
```

and this would be your  output

```
arrA:(
    apple,
    ball,
    cat,
    doll
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply, it's very clear.

I actually did search for solutions, but I think I might have thought too difficult about this.

Comment: @Prastow Dont forget to accept the ans know, so that it would be helpful for others to refer

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website so I didn't know I should checkmark it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply logic for that, You cant find answers to tricky Questions :)
You need to run a loop.

Separate string with '_'

Loop

```
for(NSString *s in ary)
{
   NSArray *a = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
   [anotherArray addObject:[a objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

and update your array..

Comment: Thank you! Actually, after posting the question I also thought about using loops, but I didn't know that I should use componentsSeparatedByString for this. Sometimes it's actually hard to know where you should look for in the documentation :) I'm now reading! Thank you!

Comment: Great.. If any answer is useful to you, keep a habit of accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Following might help you -

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"_"]; 
NSString *finalString = [originalString substringToIndex:range.location];
```

you can have this in loop.

Or you can go for `componentSeperatedByStrings`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
NSMutableArray *tmpAry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *_string in _StringAry)
{
    NSCharacterSet  *charSet  = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_0123456789"];
    _string =  [[_string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    [tmpAry addObject: [[_string copy] autorelease]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", tmpAry); // Gives the modified array
[tmpAry release];
```